# Reusing of std::unique_lock instead of creating a new one

Tags: c++, concurrency

One way to use `std::unique_lock` is

```
while (!m_exit || !m_queueOfTasks.empty()) 
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_mutex);
    std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " is ready" << std::endl;
    m_cond.wait(ul, [this]() {return !m_queueOfTasks.empty(); });
    std::function<void()> work(std::move(m_queueOfTasks.front()));
    m_queueOfTasks.pop_front();
    std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " got a new task" << std::endl;
    ul.unlock();
    work();
}
```

We could reuse the `unique_lock` instead of creating it every iteration.

Since its constructor

> Constructs a unique_lock with m as the associated mutex. Additionally
> locks the associated mutex by calling m.lock().

It means that we need to create it unlocked and lock it manually. Is it the correct code or I missed anything?

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_mutex, std::defer_lock);
while (!m_exit || !m_queueOfTasks.empty()) 
{
    ul.lock();
    std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " is ready" << std::endl;
    m_cond.wait(ul, [this]() {return !m_queueOfTasks.empty(); });
    std::function<void()> work(std::move(m_queueOfTasks.front()));
    m_queueOfTasks.pop_front();
    std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " got a new task" << std::endl;
    ul.unlock();
    work();
}
```

The question is rather technical than an attempt of optimization.

Comment: No the locks are tightly coupled to scopes : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii. The whole idea is to NOT take manual control and let destructor of a lock do its work. std::scoped_lock is normally fine, unless you need an explicit unlock then you use std::unique_lock. Have you experienced performance problems?

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes, but here I use std::unique_lock that allows manual control by design

Comment: @PepijnKramer You're probably refering to `std::lock_guard` in your comment. `std::unique_lock` is indeed designed to allow for being changed from locked to unlocked state an the other way round. In fact `std::condition_variable` relies on this.

Comment: @fabian yes indeed I meant lock_guard. Also posted before I was finished.

Comment: I am not saying that this won't work. But I would probably still use the scope to manage the lock just to avoid mistakes. And this feels like "optimization" to me (which might be needed, but it would not be my first choice)

Comment: @PepijnKramer so the answer should be: "technically correct, but don't do this in a production code". Right?

Comment: Yes that would be a good summary, also related to : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: Note that in your first approach I would just have added an extra scope (that would end just before work) instead of calling unlock explicitly.

Comment: Oh the answer just has shown that too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one thing that can break complex code if you use this pattern (but won't break your snippets): an exception being thrown.

Consider this:

```
// static variable, or more realistically a class member
static std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_mutex, std::defer_lock);
while (!m_exit || !m_queueOfTasks.empty()) 
{
    ul.lock();
    std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " is ready" << std::endl;
    m_cond.wait(ul, [this]() {return !m_queueOfTasks.empty(); });
    // exception thrown!
    std::function<void()> work(std::move(m_queueOfTasks.front()));
    m_queueOfTasks.pop_front();
    std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " got a new task" << std::endl;
    ul.unlock();
    work();
}
// m_mutex might still be locked
```

If the lock is not just a local variable and anything throws an exception between `lock()` and `unlock()`, then the mutex stays locked.

It can also happen if the lock is a local variable but you also have a try-catch block:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_mutex, std::defer_lock);
while (!m_exit || !m_queueOfTasks.empty()) 
{
    try {
        ul.lock();
        std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " is ready" << std::endl;
        m_cond.wait(ul, [this]() {return !m_queueOfTasks.empty(); });
        // exception thrown!
        std::function<void()> work(std::move(m_queueOfTasks.front()));
        m_queueOfTasks.pop_front();
        std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " got a new task" << std::endl;
        ul.unlock();
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "Exception thrown";
    }
    // m_mutex might still be locked
    work();
}
```

These things can quickly happen when working on complicated code, and is one of the reasons using scopes (and RAII) is recommended. This potential bug cannot happen when using the scope:

```
while (!m_exit || !m_queueOfTasks.empty()) 
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_mutex, std::defer_lock);
        std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " is ready" << std::endl;
        m_cond.wait(ul, [this]() {return !m_queueOfTasks.empty(); });
        // exception thrown!
        std::function<void()> work(std::move(m_queueOfTasks.front()));
        m_queueOfTasks.pop_front();
        std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " got a new task" << std::endl;
    } // lock destructor always called
    // m_mutex is unlocked no matter what
    work();
}
```

Comment: I think for the 2nd snippet _ul.unlock();_ should be below the catch, right before the _work()_ call

Comment: Unfortunately `work` needs to be scoped further than the lock.

Comment: @amplifier Ok but would you think of doing that? My point is just to illustrate a potential bug.